# rotating a list using Pandas only

Tags: python, pandas

We are all familiar with the classic question of rotating a list to the left, say:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

#rotate by two to the left
mylist[2:] + mylist[:2]

Out[4]: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2]
```

Now consider the same list, as a `Pandas` series.

```
pdlist = pd.Series(mylist)
Out[8]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
dtype: int64
```

How can I rotate it in the same way, by only using Pandas functions?

Thanks!

Comment: not a Pandas function, but a numpy function could do the shift: ``pd.Series(np.roll(pdlist, -2))`` In plain python, you could rotate with `collections.deque` and the `rotate` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
pdlist[2:].append(pdlist[:2])
```

Comment: pretty sweet. I was wondering is something can be done with `.shift()`

Comment: I don't think so (at least not in one-step) becase the `periods` parameter only accepts integer. But maybe someone knows how to do that haha.

Comment: who said that has to be in just one step? :D

Comment: `pdlist.shift(-2).dropna().append(pdlist[:2])`? It still uses `append`, though. I couldn't think in any other approach using pandas that doesn't increase the code. I liked the `numpy` approach mentioned by @sammywemmy.